# How to call a URL in C#

Tags: c#, url

Currently working with Unity, this might a super basic question, but here goes.

I need to call a URL from my app in C#. This is done for analytics purposes, and so I don't want to open a web browser or anything, just call the URL and that's it. I know about Application.OpenURL() to open the browser, but how do I achieve this without opening the browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var x = client.DownloadString("http://example.com");
```

or

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com") as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the WebClient class in the System.Net namespace.

It's a high level implementation of an HTTP client which is really easy to use.

Has a method called .DownloadString() which does exactly what you want - calls a URL using HTTP GET and returns the response as a string.